# Vue.js VSCode Vetur Emmet and Scaffold Snippets not recognized

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I am using Vue.js on VSCode, and I installed Vetur for formatting. According to [this](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/real-world-vue-js/optimizing-your-editor/) video, there should be Scaffold snippets and Emmett code completion. None of that shows up on VSCode. When I type "scaffold" into a .vue file, there's no autocomplete. When I type "h1" into a .vue file, there's also no autocomplete. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried restarting your vscode?

Comment: Yep I did! It doesn't work :(

Comment: After the extensions are installed, you need to enable them as well. Could you double check that they are enabled?

Comment: Yep, it's enabled - when I view the Vetur extension, it says "This extension is enabled globally."

Comment: Then I suggest you reinstall the extensions and see if that helps

Comment: I've tried that before, it didn't work

Answer (score 30):

Please have a look at this https://issuehunt.io/r/vuejs/vetur/issues/1325, here they explain it's not: `scaffold` but `vue`.

Comment: comment worth retaining and it makes perfect sense just to use vue.

Answer (score 8):

Just type vue instead of scaffold:

[image]

See the final result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

following configurations，then, restart vscode, it will work

```
{
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": { 
        "vue-html": "html",    
        "vue": "html"  
    }
}
```

Comment: This resolves my issue emmet suddenly stops working on on .vue files. Usually it works out of the box when you install Vetur but now I have to add this from the settings.json configuration.